# Monitoring Container CPU Utilization using Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

On Prometheus UI when I am running the below query it worked as expected

```
(sum ( rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="nginx-enabled", container="nginx"}[30s])) * 100000) /  110000
Output Returned: 23.34


container_spec_cpu_quota{namespace="nginx-enabled", container="nginx"}
Output Returned: 110000
```

But when I am trying with below query I did not see any output and no error message related to query string.

```
(sum ( rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="nginx-enabled", container="nginx"}[30s])) * 100000) / (container_spec_cpu_quota{namespace="nginx-enabled", container="nginx"})
```

Can someone please help me what I am missing, I am very very new to Prometheus Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PromQL can indeed be tricky, for example, if one happens to use a wrong data type it simply fails silently. The problem you are running into seems to be that the left-hand side of your combined query, that is, the  `(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total...` part returns a scalar value (so, exactly one value) while the right-hand side (`container_spec_cpu_quota{...}`) is a vector whose most recent value is shown only.

I tried to re-create your combined query in [PromLens](https://demo.promlens.com/), which offers a nice way to debug queries. Unfortunately, it doesn't offer `container_spec_cpu_quota` in the data so I replaced it with something close-by that is available (`container_spec_cpu_shares`).

Now, if you plug in the following query into PromLens, emulating your query, you will see that it fails as well (you will see why when you click on the `Explain` tab):

```
(sum ( rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[30s])) * 100000)
/
container_spec_cpu_shares
```

Whereas, when you aggregate the right-hand side as well, turning it into a scalar (and since it's a gauge, a simple `sum` does it), you get a result:

```
(sum ( rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[30s])) * 100000)
/
sum(container_spec_cpu_shares)
```

Further options to deal with left and right side not aligning in terms of data types, such as using the `on` or `ignoring` keyword are available via the docs in the [Vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) section.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for your help and PromLens as well :)